Passing from $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathcal{S}$ using a density argument and extra condition
I saw a proof for the following statement for the space of Schwartz functions $\mathcal{S}$:
$$
\varphi \in \mathcal{S}: \int \varphi = 0 \iff \exists \Phi\in \mathcal{S}: \Phi' = \varphi,
$$
which wasn't too surprising, since there is the same statement for the space of test functions $\mathcal{D}$, which lies densely in $\mathcal{S}$.
So for the "$\Rightarrow$"-direction, I was wondering whether a density argument would suffice to solve this (provided this statement has been proven for $\mathcal{D}$), because in the $\mathcal{D}$ case, validating that $\Phi(x) := \int_{-\infty}^x \varphi$ is compactly supported is much easier than verifying it is a Schwartz function (which was how the proof went).
However a density argument doesn't seem to be too straightforward, since given a $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}$ with $\int \varphi = 0$ and $\varphi_n \in \mathcal{D}: \varphi_n \rightarrow \varphi$, we would as well need that each $\int \varphi_n = 0$, which I don't think needs to be the case?
Is this a lost cause to proof or are there techniques to go around this? I'm mostly interested in not just a way to salvage this but also maybe a proof technique involving density argument + extra conditions on the approximations.
